infowindow personalizado con button que no detecta el click
#XML este xml contiene mas elementos pero solo no funciona el boton#
<FrameLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSupervisar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/morado"
    android:text="Supervisar"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="390dp"
    android:onClick="btnSupervisar"
    android:translationZ="1000dp"
    />
</FrameLayout>

'''Codigo Kotlin: si abre la ventana con el boton , pero al presionar el boton no detecta el click'''
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(object : InfoWindowAdapter{
override fun getInfoContents(marker: Marker): View? {           
val view = LayoutInflater.from(appContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null)

val btnSupervisar = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnSupervisar)
btnSupervisar.setOnClickListener {
Log.d("InfoWindow", "Botón Supervisar clickeado") 
var dialog = 
FragmentDetalleTaller.newInstance(marker.title.toString())
dialog.show(parentFragmentManager, "detalle_taller")
}
return view
}     
override fun getInfoWindow(marker: Marker): View? {
return null
}

public fun btnSupervisar(){
Log.d("InfoWindow", "Botón Supervisar clickeado")          
var dialog = FragmentDetalleTaller.newInstance("")
dialog.show(parentFragmentManager, "detalle_taller")
}
})

'''lo intento con el onclick y no funciona, lo intento con el setOnclick y tampoco'''
